# How to handle routes in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning api on rails,and my code is below

routes.rb

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do

    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, :only => [:show]
    end

  end
end
```

users_controllers.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

when I run the rails server with `localhost:3000/users/1` then It gives me the error `No route matches`
Then i checked routes using `rake routes` and it is included in my routes

```
`api_user    GET     /users/:id(.:format)     api/v1/users#show'
```

but i don't know why it gives me the error

api_constraints.rb

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.marketplace.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
api.lvh.me:3000/api/v1/users/1
```

You've setup a constraint that requires an api sub domain. You'll need to remove the constraint to make the following work:

```
lvh.me:3000/api/v1/users/1
```

Note: lvh.me points to 127.0.0.1

Comment: already tried that, but it gives me the same error and it is giving http 404 stauts when i inspect the element

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into consideration the sub domain constraint. I missed that on my original post.

Comment: I have tried all your links but it gives me the same error, I have edited my post with api_constraints.rb file if it gives u some hint towards the answer

Comment: Interesting. I would recommend removing the constraint and going from there. Also, are you sure the user with id 1 exists in the db? Are you getting a routing error or ActiveRecord record not found error.

Comment: It's my mistake, actually i got the answer when i tried api.lvh.me:3000/api/v1/users/1